# Taxonomy panel page visibility problem

Tags: views, panels

I have a visibility problem.
I have a taxonomy/term page managed with panels. There are 2 panel pane who display 2 views.
The problem is that I [the admin..] can see the page correctly but all the other users see nothing except a block I putted on top of panel pane for test.

I read the markup and I can see the panel but not the panel panes. This panel panes have no visibility rule and the views inside it have the default Access rule.

How can I find where is the issue?
Why only the user 'admin' can see this pages?

Comment: What is in the two Views, and have you verified that anonymous users have access to that content? It doesn't matter whether a visibility rule affects the content or not of the users don't have permission to see the underlying content, such as taxonony terms.

Comment: Solved: In the view there are some products and the anonimous didn't have the permissions to acces the products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure this is related to permission:

A few pointers to help you debug:

1. Please check the permission of the components components you are trying to display through views. For example, a field is related to displaying an uploaded video. Anonymous users might ot be having permission to view it, though have the permission to view, but still they will not be able to access the stuff. So try to figure out what modules are responsible for the field you display through view, and then check the permissions coming from that module.

Actually this will be the only one that looks most probable to me. hope this helps.